# squid ssl proxy (NON TRANSPARENT)

Tags: proxy, ssl

I have been searching google for hours, I know this is possible but all google gives is transparent proxy ssl results and I do NOT want squid transparent. I'm going to be pushing proxy settings via GPO and want to have squid handle both http and https.

I'm not trying to inspect, filter or cache anything just want the proxy running on ssl so I can set acls for web browsing.

Does anyone know how to set squid for ssl proxy when the client browser is directly or via auto discovery set to use a proxy (non transparent)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My squid proxy is set to:

> http_port 8080 transparent

in my squid config file.  I then push the proxy settings via GPO to my workstations and secure the setting so that users cannot change the proxy settings.  I have HTTP and HTTPS traffic that works without any problem.

This is what the rest of my squid.conf file looks like.

```
acl biz_network src 10.0.0.0/12 
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED  
acl biz_hours time M T W H F 07:00-21:00

http_access allow ncsa_users biz_network biz_hours
```

With this I have set on my Server 2008 in a GPO:
User Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Internet Explorer Maintenance -> Connection/Proxy Settings -> 10.0.2.25:8080

You can try and take away the transparent after the

> http_port 8080

This should still work.  I had mine like that for a long time.